# Do I need to save a different copy of content in MongoDB database for the Arabic translation in next.js?

Tags: javascript, internationalization, next.js14

For arabic translation of database saved content in next.js do we need to save different copy in database for Arabic content or put strings in a json file? What is the best approach? I am using MongoDB.

I am seeing json strings every where in google search results or on youtube.